# Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I have a list in SharePoint 2010 which was working ok until 500 records had been added. At this time, when filtering by a particular column(employee name), the following error occurs:

> 'Attempted to use an object that has ceased to exist. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80030102 (STG_E_REVERTED))'

The view is grouped by employee ID, which is an additional column of a lookup field of employee name in the employee list. The view item limit is 1000.

The List View threshold is set at 50000 and this is SharePoint 2010.

Comment: check this https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/798a26cd-12d9-4ce0-bd67-c54a8955e07d/attempted-to-use-an-object-that-has-ceased-to-exist-exception-from-hresult-0x80030102?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious how many lookup and people columns in view

Comment: Do you have any custom solution deployed in the farm?

Comment: Yes, there are custom solutions in the farm.

Comment: @user33047 I had the same issue and removing "Group by" from the default view,resolved the issue.